# Checking a box in a unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I am trying to test a condition in my unit test where if a box is checked another button turns green if not the button turns red.  Is there a way in the unit test to write checkbox is checked `assert.equal(button, color.Green)` and checkbox not checked `assert.equal(button, color.Red)`.  I have looked around and have been unable to find anything for c# that where buttons and check boxes can be manipulated.  How would I do this?

What I want to test is when the user uses the gui using WinForms provides and checks the checkbox the button turn green.

Comment: Your question is unclear for me. Please show your efforts and be more specific.

Comment: What UI are you using? WebForms?

Comment: UI sorry that I didn't explain.  I added it to my question

Comment: Still no mention... Is it `WinForms` or `WebForms`?

Comment: WinForms not WebFroms

Answer (score 0):

Assert can check almost anything, there's no special code "for buttons" you just need to figure out which things to check.

```
Assert.AreEqual(Button.ForeColor, System.Drawing.Color.Green);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.forecolor(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: How do I simulate the user checking the checkbox?

Comment: That's a completely different question, and it isn't worth asking here, because: https://www.google.com/search?q=How+do+I+simulate+the+user+checking+the+checkbox - which you really should be embarassed by. AGF - Always Google First!